# increasing torque of a sewing machine motor

Tags: motor, amperage, torque

I have a very small table saw (Harbor Freight "Mighty Mite") that is rated at 0.9 amps and 1/12 hp with max RPM of 14000 (a sewing machine motor). I use a jewelers saw blade and cut a very small channel approx. 1/8 of an inch deep for guitar frets. It works fine on soft woods but will sometimes bog down on hard woods. If I replace it with a 1.5 amp sewing machine motor with a 9000 RPM would it increase the torque to more likely make the cuts on hard woods?

Comment: rpm and torque are not always related, so it's hard to say. torque has more to do with winding and RPM with efficiency. more current equals more torque. If you're replacing it anyway, see if over-driving it doesn't help; if it's not over-heating it's probably fine.

Comment: Most low cost tools run universal motors. You can lookup the speed torque curve of a universal motor, very little torque at high rpm, lots of torque at low rpm

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question.

On the one hand, it's clear that the larger motor will give you better torque. The combination of higher current and lower rpm should give about twice the torque.

On the other hand, there is no guarantee that this will be enough. To begin with, a motor will only bog down if the load is too great, and for a saw the load will be pretty much proportional to the feed rate. A basic question arises - if your saw is bogging down, why don't you just reduce your feed pressure and cut more slowly? Assuming that you realize that you could just cut more slowly, but don't, then there must be something else at play, such as the cut quality with slower feed and harder wood. So it's possible that using a beefier, slower motor will not give you an acceptable cut. And I don't know of a way to tell in advance.

Comment: Bingo, that's the real issue here, feed rate. Saw blades work on repetitively chipping away very small amounts of material at high speed. Lowering the speed of the blade may result in MUCH worse performance, because the teeth will be making contact for longer and heating up faster, which generally weakens the blade steel so the teeth wear out faster. If the blade was designed for 14k RPM, slowing it to 9k RPM is likely totally inappropriate. All you really need do, as WRB posted, is slow down your feed rate. Patience my friend, patience...

Answer (score 0):

The published ratings for motorized consumer products are very difficult to interpret. They usually describe motor test conditions that can not be achieved during normal use of the product. The motors used must be either universal motors or permanent-magnet DC motors. In either case, the speed will decrease considerably under load. The current given may or may not be a safe operating current for an extended period of use.

It is likely that the 1.5 amp motor can safely provide more torque for an extended use time, but there is no way to know for sure without trying it. Even if the motor doesn't overheat, mechanical wear may shorten the life of the tool.

Comment: And the fact that the nominal rpm is lower almost guarantees that the torque will be greater.

Answer (score 0):

There are many of different types of sewing motors. The most used is universal motor with variable series resistor aka pedal, or some SCR controlled AC speed controller. If you hear the 50/60Hz noise then it's an old fashioned sewing motor. Newer and costly sewing machines have permanent magnet DC motor with encoder feedback. If you want a cheap and good solution, then a permanent magnet DC motor with speed controller is the way to go. More costly and yet better is the BLDC motor + controller.

Answer (score 0):

A quick but rough analysis: 1.5A is a 67% increase over 0.9A, a 67% increase in electrical power into the motor.  *Assuming* the two motors have the same efficiency and are similarly rated, there should be a corresponding 67% increase in mechanical output power. Power is proportional to speed times torque, so a decrease from 14 to 9 krpm corresponds to an increase in torque of 56% if output power is the same. So you might expect to see 1.56 * 1.67 = 2.6 times as much torque from the larger motor, though at a lower speed.